# In HTML, how do I get AJAX to post button click to .py using jquery and cgi?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, ajax

I wrote a Python script that inserts data into a PostgreSQL database.  I have a simple HTML page with a couple of buttons, and I am having a hard time posting the data from the button click on the client to Python CGI on the server side.

Here is what the HTML, ajax and javascript look like:

```
''<div class="note" id="(Untitled)">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-2.1.1.js">
$(function () {
            $('#1').on('click', function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "~/pythonscript.py",
                            datatype: "json",
                            data: JSON.stringify({
                                'param': {
                                    "1"
                                }
                            }),
                            success: function (response) {
                                alert(response);
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    $('#2').on('click', function () {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "~/pythonscript.py",
                                datatype: "json",
                                data: JSON.stringify({
                                    'param': {
                                        "2"
                                    }
                                }),
                                success: function (response) {
                                    alert(response);
                                }
                            })
                        }
                        )
```

```
   <body>
         <a href="index2.html">
        <button id="1">one</button><br>
        <button id="2">two</button><br>
        </a>
   </body>
```

Here is what some of the Python looks like:

```
def cgi_get_from_ajax(self):
    import json
    import cgi
    data = cgi.FieldStorage()
    chosen = data.value
    return chosen

def set_choice(self):
    process = Name_of_class()
    choice = process.cgi_get_from_ajax()
    entry = []
    if choice == '1':
         entry = [1,0,0,0]
    else:
        entry = [0,0,0,1]
            return entry
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing you code to:

```
data: {param: '2'} --- in the jQuery
data["param"].value ---- in the Python script
```

This usually works for me. Maybe it does for you too ;)

Comment: Yes, thank you very kindly for your reply, and I do appreciate it Phillip,  However, I tried http post requests, tried php, PSP, WSGI, MOd_python. The rest of the world seems to get this to work. So what gives? I tried with MYSQL instead of Postgres. also Psycopg2, There seems there are a dozen ways to do this seemingly simple thing. And quite frankly the super obvious eludes me.  It's actually easier to find linear algebra solutions in python than this...

Comment: ok anyway it was worth a shot. i just thought that at least one anwer is better than none.